# Help me to write this in mathematical term (notation)

Tags: linear-algebra

A, B is a constant matrix.

I want to define $f(x,y)$ such that $A*f \geq |A - B|$

where $f$ is a function that output a scalar. How should I write the line above in proper math notation?

Comment: I cannot sort out what function $f$ is supposed to do.  You wrote $f(x,y)$, which means $f$ is a function of two arguments, but it is unclear what *kind* of things those arguments are supposed to be (matrices of some kind?).  To make clear the source of a function's arguments, it is customary to write a declaration $f:D\to R$, where $D$ is the domain of the function (you can write a Cartesian product if there is more than one argument) and $R$ is the codomain (the set where results are produced).  Again, saying $f$ is a scalar function suggests $R$ is to be some "scalars".

Comment: $A-B$ outputs a matrix, $f$ should output a scalar. So it is not entirely clear (to me) what you are looking for...?

Comment: It is unlikely that $f$ will exist, since for general matrices $A$ and $B$, there will almost never be a multiple of $A$ that gives $A-B$.

Comment: upper bound, i meant . Let me change that: define $f(x,y)$ such that $A*f \leq |A - B|$

Comment: The left side is a matrix, the right side is a scalar?

Comment: What do you mean by $A * f \ge |A-B|$? The left-hand side is a matrix, and the right-hand side is a scalar now? How do you define $|A-B|$?

Comment: every element of a matrix.

Comment: It might be clearer if you gave an example of what you want to describe "in mathematical notation", building on what has already been proposed.  In its present form I'll be inclined to vote to close for lack of clarity and context.